# ¿Cómo mantener una sesión en NextJS?

Tags: next.js

estoy pasando una app de react a next y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un formulario que inicia sesión, al iniciar sesión hace una petición a una api hecha en node y express, la api devuelve un token, este token lo guardo cifrado en localstorage. Ahora, después de iniciar sesión, hago una redirección a /dashboard, el problema es que si vuelvo a la ruta que muestra el formulario, simplemente lo muestra, en teoría debería redireccionar todas las rutas que no sean /dashboard a esta misma si se ha iniciado sesión.

Estoy usando redux para almacenar la información, de igual manera si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión y se va a la ruta /dashboard debería volver al login.

Aún no logro encontrar un respuesta a este problema, agradecería mucho que me ayuden a encontrar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Probaste haciendo un efecto y revisando si el item en el localStorage existe, si existe entonces redireccionar a `/dashboard`?

En `login.js`:

```js
const router = useRouter()

useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (token) router.push('/dashboard')
}, [localStorage])
```